# Is it safe to delete the quota.user file?

Tags: centos, quota

Is it okay to delete the `quota.user` file from the root directory?  This file is 2.7GB in size and I need to wipe it from the system.  I ran:

```
$ quotaoff -avug
$ mv quota.user quotaold.user
$ quotaon -avug
$ mv quotaold.user /another/place
```

So far all seems well.

I was looking for a way to truncate this file but couldn't find anything so I decided to just try removing it instead.

I am running *CentOS* release 5 (Final) on Xen using cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually using quotas, you will want to regenerate it with `quotacheck`, or all your users will be back to zero used space as far as the quota system knows.